# mysql does not replace all positional parameterrs in INSERT ON DUPLICATE

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO company_benefits
 (CompanyId, A , B , C , D , E , F , G , H , I , J , K , L , M) 
  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  A=%s , B=%s , C=%s , D=%s , E=%s,
  F=%s , G=%s , H=%s , I=%s , J=%s,
  K=%s , L=%s , M=%s;
```

There are **27** positional parameters in that query.

I have a list of tuples where each tuple contains 27 values. One of them looks like this:

```
(533, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I then use `mycursor.executemany(sql, params)`

However, I get the following error:

> Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

I have printed and confirmed that both the SQL statment as well as **each** tuple in my list of tuples contain 27 paramerters.

Does positional parameters replacing does not work with `Insert/Duplicate`?

Comment: why do you have duplicate column name E?

Comment: My mistake. While making a dummy column name array, I inserted E twice. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
INSERT INTO company_benefits
(CompanyId, A , B , C , D , E , F , G , H , I , J , K , L , M) 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
A=VALUES(A), B=VALUES(B), C=VALUES(C), D=VALUES(D), E=VALUES(E),
F=VALUES(F), G=VALUES(G) , H=VALUES(H), I=VALUES(I), J=VALUES(J),
K=VALUES(K), L=VALUES(L), M=VALUES(M);
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much. :)